# Algorithm for Simple Graph Given Degree Sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Are there an algorithm that provides a fastest way to construct simple graph given a degree sequence?  Are there any other interesting problems around this area that I might be overlooking and should consider exploring?